# Create dummy audio file in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, unit-testing, core-audio, avaudioplayer

I woud like to programatically create and save to disk a dummy audio file to use in unit tests involving `AVAudioPlayer`.

What's the simplest way to do this in iOS?

Comment: do you want to create it programmatically?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A colleague suggested an alternative solution: create the smallest audio file possible with [Audacitiy](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/), get its bytes, and copy them into the code.

This is the result:

```
const char bytes[] = {0x52, 0x49, 0x46, 0x46, 0x26, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x57, 0x41, 0x56, 0x45, 0x66, 0x6d, 0x74, 0x20, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x44, 0xac, 0x0, 0x0, 0x88, 0x58, 0x1, 0x0, 0x2, 0x0, 0x10, 0x0, 0x64, 0x61, 0x74, 0x61, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xfc, 0xff};
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:sizeof(bytes)];
NSString* filePath = [path_ stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.wav"];
[data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
audioURL_ = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
```

Comment: Yeah this can be another easier way to do it. I thought you want to generate it programmatically & wave file should be different everytime. :)

Comment: the audio file created by this method cant be played, any particular reason?

Answer (score 0):

You can either record some random noise for some duration using AVAudioRecord.

<strike>Alternatively, you can create one wave file from scratch using details given in following link : http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/45613-creating-audio-programmatically.html</strike>

Edit: link is dead. Try this https://web.archive.org/web/20120701191443/http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/45613-creating-audio-programmatically.html

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"WavHeader" ofType:@"wav"];
```

NSMutableData *audioData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

int samples = 22050;

uint8_t dataToRecord[samples];

int x;

for(x = 0; x < samples; x++) {

```
// populate the "dataToRecord" array with audio data. //
```

}

[audioData appendBytes:(const void *)dataToRecord length:samples];

```
// Get path to documents folder and set a file name  //
```

[audioData writeToFile:pathToFile atomically:YES];

Comment: Thanks! I'll play around with AVAudioRecord. However, I don't love unit tests enough to study wav headers, as the link suggests. :)

Comment: And the link doesn't work… That's why you should include essential points right in your answer.

Comment: The link is a click bait? clicked and went to weird site!